# Android AWS S3 if I build with proguard application crashes with Failed to parse regional endpoints

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have built an Android application that uses AWS S3.  I am successful in building the application. The application works fine if I compile and execute on a simulator.

If I try to release the application (built using progaurd), when I try to run the application it crashes with the message "Failed to parse regional endpoints".  I tried different progaurd configurations, trying different way of including JARs but nothing is working.

I am using AWS sdk 1.7.1.1.

Please let me know if you have faced similar issue and found a solution.

Thanks
   - SVJK

Comment: Welcome to SO. No one here is likely going to be able to diagnose your issue unless you post some code demonstrating the problem.  A minimal example is usually all that's needed.

Comment: Are you using the setRegion call? You could try using the setEndpoint call instead as this should avoid parsing the endpoints file.  Unfortunately Proguard strips out any non-class files.

Comment: did you fix this? i am running into a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284562/proguard-aws-s3-issue